# Make the `[edit]` pseudo-link in comments easier to see

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, magic-links

The `[edit]` pseudolink in a comment turns into the word "edit" linked to the edit page for the post that the comment is attached to.

However, I find that by default, the link isn't very easy to make out as such, because the link text color is rather similar to the text color. This is exacerbated by the fact that the word "edit" is rather short. For the people who need that advice the most, namely newcomers to the site, it can be *very* easy to miss the fact that there is an action "edit" on posts.

Hence, I propose **making the `[edit]` link easier to see in a block of text.** I normally use boldface (like `**[edit]**` in the Markdown input) for this purpose but I imagine underlining or a different background color could work as well. In a cramped comment trying to explain to a newcomer in particular what might be wrong with their post, the four asterisks just to make the "edit" stand out a little often feels to me like an unnecessary penalty.

Comment: Shouldn't this then be true for all pseudo links?

Comment: @rene Maybe. But I find `[edit]` is the one that suffers the most from this problem, so that's what my question focuses on.

Comment: One never stop learning... didn't know that [edit] is a magic link. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You had to try it, didn't you? You couldn't just take my word for it? ;)

Comment: That, and I really had to edit in order to add relevant tag. :-)

Comment: Related feature requests with an alternate approach to the same problem (that I think digs closer at the root of the problem): ["_Inform new users about the option to edit their own post when adding a comment_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235029/997587), and [another marked as a dup but a more fleshed out proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273507/997587).