# Let it be more clear for new users that their questions can be edited anytime

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, new-users

After [the comment I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132000/analysing-customized-youtube-urls?noredirect=1#comment106396455_60132000) on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60132000/12511801) from a new user, [their response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132000/analysing-customized-youtube-urls?noredirect=1#comment106399351_60132000) was:

> thanks for the corrective feedback, **as this is my first question ever
>   on Stackoverflow. Didn't even know I could edit the question again**,
>   which I will based on your advices. If you can, please tell me if my
>   new question is more appropriate. Thanks. – Filipe Santos 9 mins ago

By this comment, the new user didn't know about editing their question.

Hence, this might be use for future modifications of the help page and related material first shown to new users.

Is there plan(s) to handle the correct or more direct tutorial/information/guide to new users?

---

[Linked/duplicated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235029/inform-new-users-about-the-option-to-edit-their-own-post-when-adding-a-comment) doesn't answer this question - it only saw comment and say the OP about edit their own answer instead using comments - which is not what my question is about. My point was some like the question-wizard and there it's explained that they can edit ther question anytime.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ status-planned .. it is in the 6 to 8 years timeframe now ....

Comment: @rene Looks like there were more important features to implement became in the way ;-)

Comment: That one can edit questions is part of the tour.

Comment: People don't read what we tell them. Especially new users don't. The only motivation is that they wan't to get their questions answered, no matter how VLQ or useful these are. Just my 2¢ of experience. Conclusion: It's not worth the efforts.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me like the system is working perfectly! A new user joined, and on their very first question, an experienced member of the community told them about a feature they hadn't noticed. Yay!

Sure, you could have documentation, tutorials, videos, whatever, but the simple truth is that most people don't look at these. For instance, editing is mentioned in the tour and there's an "edit" link right there under every post. I don't really see how it would be helpful to make it even more obvious.

Instead, we have helpful users like yourself who take the time to educate newcomers. This is so common, we even have a magic link for edit: if you use `[edit]` in a comment under a question, it will be rendered as a link which, when clicked, will take you straight to the editing interface.

So, basically, thank you for being helpful but I doubt there's much to improve here.